# Django REST-framework: Using serializer for simple ForeignKey-relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, serialization

I'm using the django REST-framework and try to map a simple foreign-key relationship to provide related data for further use, similar to the following request:

[Using reverse relationships with django-rest-framework's serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139378/using-reverse-relationships-with-django-rest-frameworks-serializer?rq=1][1])

Instead of a result, I receive the following exception:

*Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `album_name` on serializer `AlbumSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `int` instance.
Original exception text was: 'int' object has no attribute 'album_name'.*

**Models:**

```
    class Album(models.Model):
        album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Track(models.Model):
        # album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        order = models.IntegerField()
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        duration = models.IntegerField()

        class Meta:
            unique_together = ('album', 'order')
            ordering = ['order']

        def __unicode__(self):
            return '%d: %s' % (self.order, self.title)
```

**Serializers:**

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('id', 'album_name', 'artist' )
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    album_id = AlbumSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('order', 'title', 'duration', 'album_id')
```

**View:**

```
class TrackView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Track.objects.all().select_related('album')
    serializer_class = serializers.TrackSerializer
```

**What I have tried so far:**

1. Serializing Albums with related tracks as nested serializers, using a reverse relationship => **works**
2. Doing the work just for the TrackSerializer without nested Album => **works**
3. Doing the work just for the AlbumSerializer => **works**
4. Using the TrackSerializer as shown in the code-section but reducing the AlbumSerializer by every
   field except for the primary key 'id' => **works** (but I would need the
   whole data set of album)
5. Changed the nested Serializer to a many-relationship by setting *many=True*. => dumps, since the framework tries to iterate on all fields of AlbumSerializer.

Since I'm running out of ideas and material to browse for I'm asking the question:
How to list all or single attributes (!= PrimaryKey) of Album for each Track in regards to my example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`album_id` in `Track` model is just album's primary key, so you have `int` type in error description. You need to specify whole `album` object by using `album` field instead of `album_id`:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    album = AlbumSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('order', 'title', 'duration', 'album')
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much @neverwalkaloner, solved my (seemingly simple, bust cost me hours of troubleshooting...)-issue!